# Download CSV in Shiny app every 24 hours & display download time

Tags: r, csv, shiny

I have a CSV that I want to download. I do not want it to download every time a user joins or uses the app.

I want to run the code every 24 hours and also display any of 1) timer since last download 2) timer until next download 3) timestamp of last download

Below is what I have right now, which works, but will probably cause unnecessary downloads. Is doing something with invalidatelater going to work or is there a better way?

```
CSV.Path <- "https://oracleselixir-downloadable-match-data.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/2021_LoL_esports_match_data_from_OraclesElixir_20210404.csv"
download.file(CSV.Path, "lol2021")
lol2021 <- read.csv("lol2021")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to approach this:

1. Check to see if it should be downloaded when the app starts; if the file is more recent than 24h, do not re-download it. This can be resolved fairly easily with:

   ```r
   fileage <- difftime(Sys.time(), file.info("data")["mtime"][[1]], units = "day")
   if (is.na(fileage) || fileage > 1) {
     CSV.Path <- "https://oracleselixir-downloadable-match-data.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/2021_LoL_esports_match_data_from_OraclesElixir_20210404.csv"
     download.file(CSV.Path, "lol2021")
   }
   lol2021 <- read.csv("lol2021")
   ```

   (The `is.na` is there in case the file does not exist.)

   One complicating factor with this is that two simultaneous users might attempt to download it at the same time. There should likely be some mutex file-access control here if that is a possibility.
2. Make sure this script is run every 24h, regardless of what users are or are not using the app. On what type of server are you running this app? Something like shiny-server does not do cron-like running, I believe, and you might not be able to guarantee that the app is "awake" every 24h. RStudio Connect does allow scheduled jobs, which might be a consideration for you.

   Lacking that, if you have good access to the server, you might just add it as a cron job using `Rscript` or similar to download and overwrite the file.

Note about mutex file access: many networked filesystems (common in cloud and server architectures) do not guarantee file locking. A common technique is to download into a temporary file and then move (or copy) this temp file into the "real" file name in one step. This guards against the possibility that one process is reading from the file while another process is writing to it ... partial-file reads will be a frustrating and difficult-to-reproduce bug.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I understand what 1. is doing, but I do not understand how I can see it. What code would actually output the time difference? This code errors : file.info(lol2021)["mtime"][[1]].  As for 2, this is just going to be hosted on shinyapps.io. It is just a project I am working on as practice and will likely not have multiple users at the same time.

Comment: Did you forget quotes? I used `file.info("lol2021")`, not `file.info(lol2021)`. Since you're putting this on shinyapps.io, I think my first suggestion is likely the simplest to use at the moment.